# Convert tree to intermediate format

Tags: compiler-construction

I have been rewriting the code generation from my abstract syntax tree and it's still not correct. :-(

First, I did it simply starting at the bottom

```
1    2
 \  /
  mul   5
    \  /
     add
      |
```

If I start with add -> recursively call codegen on all inputs -> mul and add them befor add, I get as expected

```
a = mul 1 2
b = add a 5
```

The problem is, if I reference the same node twice, like:

```
1    2
 \  /
  mul   5
   | \  /
   |  sub
   |  /
   add
    |
```

This would call "mul 1 2" twice, and generate:

```
a = mul 1 2
b = sub a 5
c = mul 1 2
d = add c a
```

Now, I can fix that, if the node only generates the code the first time its called any subsequent times it will just return the result variable, in this example a.

Unfortunately this stops working if I want to generate branches. The codegen will insert the line the first time it's called (inside a branch) and if it's used outside the branch, the reference to the variable does not exist. Example:

```
    1    2
     \  /
 5    mul    3
  \  /   \  /
   sub    add
     \    /
true - if
```

This will generate, with the algorithm I currently have:

```
branch true : label1
jump label2:

label1:
a = mul 1 2     <-- inserts code
b = sub 5 a
jump end:

label2:
c = add a 3     <--- references a, which is not valid here
jump end:

end:
result = PHI [b, label1], [c, label2]
```

I guess I need a different approach, can somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: That's a graph, not a tree, and if you are coalescing common expressions, you'll need to be more careful about things like conditionals. In this particular case you could lift the computation out of the conditional, but you might want to do that in your CSE analysis.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did realize it's not a tree anymore. I guess my question really was if there's a different algorithm to codegen a graph. I fixed it now by intersecting all nodes from both conditions and codegen them before the branch. It did not turn out as hacky as I feared.